Sampling Brownian Bridge Positions in 3D with Identical Distances Between Samples
The objectivive is the following: place beads in a chain randomly, given the number of and the distance between the beads, as well as the start- and end-point.
While this could certainly be achieved with some springs and a force-relaxation procedure, I anticipate that a more performant solution would be to model this as a Wiener process / Brownian bridge. How can this be implemented?

Here is my best progress:
There is a great explanation in 1D, time-dependent, with an example implementation ("The Anticipatory Gaussian Process Way") to be found here. I have tried to generalise this to the 3D case where I take a step with a specific size (i.e., fixed distance from one sampled coordinates to the next) each time-step as such:
import numpy as np


class BrownianMotionProcess:

    def __init__(
        self,
        start: tuple,
        end: tuple,
        step_size: float = 1.0,
        times: int = 1024,
    ) -> None:
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.step_size = step_size
        self.times = times
        self.time_steps = np.linspace(0, end[0] - start[0], num=times + 1) / (
            end[0] - start[0]
        )
        self.scale = np.sqrt((end[0] - start[0]) / float(times))
        self.deterministic = start[1] + np.array(
            [t * (end[1] - start[1]) for t in self.time_steps]
        )

    def sample(self) -> np.array:
        # "Normal" random walk
        brownian_motion = [self.start[1]]
        for _ in range(self.times):
            alpha = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi)
            beta = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi)
            brownian_motion.append(
                brownian_motion[-1]
                + self.step_size
                * np.array(
                    [
                        np.cos(beta) * np.sin(alpha),
                        np.sin(beta) * np.sin(alpha),
                        np.cos(alpha),
                    ]
                )
            )
        brownian_motion = np.array(brownian_motion)
        # "close the bridge"
        return (
            self.deterministic
            + brownian_motion
            - np.array([(brownian_motion[-1]) * t for t in self.time_steps])
        )


my_bb_process = BrownianMotionProcess(
    [0, np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])],
    [
        1,
        np.array(
            [
                1.0,
                1.0,
                1.0,
            ]
        ),
    ],
    step_size=3,
    times=100,
)

coords = my_bb_process.sample()
distances = []
for i in range(1, coords.shape[0]):
    dist = np.linalg.norm(coords[i, :] - coords[i - 1, :])
    distances.append(dist)

# ideally, min = max = mean = step_size
print(
    "Min {}, max {}, mean {}".format(min(distances), max(distances), np.mean(distances))
)

However, with this implementation as seen in the code above, the step size (i.e., the norm of the distance between two subsequent coordinates) is not correct anymore after the "close the bridge" step, due to the addition of the corrections needed to recover the desired end position.
How can I obtain the desired coordinates with the correct step-size?

You are assuming a lot of prior knowledge from your readers if you only say "with this implementation, the step size is not correct anymore after rescaling". Tell us what your expectation is, what it is you observe, how the two differ, and what you have already done to assess what the issue may be. Be explicit in your question, rather than letting us guess what it is you expect.

Thank you for your comment, @WolfgangBangerth, I have consequently edited my question and hope it is more clear now what I was referring to.

It's not significantly better, though :-( You say the distance is wrong. So tell us what your program produces, and how that differs from what you expect. In fact, tell us numeric values for what you expect and numeric values for what you get.

I feel like my example code of what I have so far could be distracting a bit from the initially posed question, I added it just because it is good practice to show some of what I tried.
To answer your question: my code produces 3D coordinates of a random walk between the start and end point as expected. However, the step size is not 3 as requested in the example code, but some numeric, random values in that ballpark (between 2 and 4 for an exemplaric run with 100 steps). I understand from the code why that happens. I do not understand conceptually how I can achieve what I want without it.
